# Bootstrap кнопка не совпадает по высоте с выпадающим списком

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Код

```
 <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col col-md-1">
                        <select class="form-control mr-sm-2 my-sm-0" name="rate" type ="number">
                            <option>1</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                            <option>3</option>
                            <option>4</option>
                            <option>5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-md-1">
                        <button class="btn btn-info mr-sm-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                            <h6 class="text-center">Оценить!</h6>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Результат

[image: Кнопка]

Как сделать чтобы кнопка совпадала по высоте с выпадающим списком?

Comment: как минимум уберите h6 из кнопки. поскольку теги h добавляют отступ снизу. Либо добавьте свой css для `.btn .h6` в котором уберите этот отступ

Comment: @DmitryKozlov это абсолютно правильно! Заменил на a6 и все стало ок. Оформите пожалуйста как ответ, чтобы я мог засчитать его.